# Deleting records by passing comma separated values SQL Server & C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to delete records from my SQL Server database table by passing multiple values as comma separated string using the below query and ado.net `ExecuteNonQuery()` method. Here I am passing the table name, column name and comma separated values.

```
string delQuery = "DELETE FROM " + delTblName + 
                  " WHERE " + delColumnName + " IN (" + toDel+ ")";
```

The deletion process is successful if the full list of values in `toDel` has no issues. Assume that if there is a foreign key conflict with any of the value, the entire statement will be terminated and no records will be deleted.

Since the number of elements in `toDel` variable is big I cannot use sequential processing and also not able to use a stored procedure as per the requirement.

I need to delete based on the successful elements and return the erroneous ones from this method. Any help would be appreciated.

Used the below code using Parameters

```
try
{
   using (var sc = new SqlConnection(dbConnString))
     using (var cmd = sc.CreateCommand())
     {
         sc.Open();
         cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM @delTblName WHERE @delColumnName IN ( @valConcat) ";                                       

         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@delTblName", tblName);


         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@delColumnName", delColumnName);


         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valConcat", nosConcat);


         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

         rowsAffected = rowsAffected + cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
catch
{

}
```

Got this error - Must declare the table variable "@delTblName".

Comment: Use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) and you are good to go.

Comment: Tried but getting error because I want to create dynamic query by passing table name also as a parameter. Also I want to get the error making values from IN ( toDel) clause.

Comment: Can you show us the parameterised code and related error message?

Comment: How are you detecting any errors? Is the essential requirement to delete those records that you can and ignore the other?

Comment: @destination-data - Qn edited.

Comment: 2 questions: you mentioned you are not able to use stored procedures. is that a requirement? what version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: @Balah - It is a requirement . I need to do all these sql operations from code itself. Same code is using for multiple dbs (say like more than 50) and tables. We cant put the Stored procedures in all dbs. The version tha t I'm using is 2014

Comment: To get the erroneous rows will require a lot of work for doing it in code (mainly dynamically checking each foreign key first for clashing data). Would you be fine with batching the deletes and accepting that if there is an error, it is somewhere in a batch, rather than an individual row?

Comment: @ByteCruncher, I edited the title of the question. If I misunderstood the main point of the question, please edit it further.

Comment: Roughly how many elements are there in `toDel`?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - you have changed the title based on your answer. The actual need is not only finding the foreign key conflicts and delete.

Comment: @Balah - It can be a maximum of 15k elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of using stored procedures or not, you have two contradicting requirements:

1. You want to delete rows in batches, not one-by-one. For the sake of speed.
2. You want the delete operation to complete partially ignoring possible constraint violations.

I don't know how to make `DELETE` statement work partially. One statement is the minimal atomic amount of work, so if one row out of 1000 violates the constraint, the whole statement will be rolled back.

This leads to the following generic idea. Before attempting to `DELETE` in one statement that affects many rows, make sure that the whole list of affected rows can be deleted. Explicitly check that there is nothing in the data that can prevent the rows that you are going to delete from being deleted. The actual check depends on your constraints. Identify those rows that can't be deleted and remove them from the main `DELETE` list.

**Example**

Two tables - `TestMaster` and `TestDetails` with a one-to-many relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestMaster](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MasterData] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TestMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestDetails](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MasterID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DetailData] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TestDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestDetails]  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TestDetails_TestMaster] FOREIGN KEY([MasterID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TestMaster] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TestDetails_TestMaster]
GO
```

Some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestMaster] ([ID],[MasterData]) VALUES
(1, 'Master1'),
(2, 'Master2'),
(3, 'Master3'),
(4, 'Master4');

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestDetails] ([ID],[MasterID],[DetailData]) VALUES
(10, 1, 'Detail10'),
(11, 1, 'Detail11'),
(20, 2, 'Detail20');
```

Simple attempt to `DELETE` items `(1, 2, 3, 4)`:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[TestMaster]
WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

This fails:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 13
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_TestDetails_TestMaster". The conflict occurred in database "AdventureWorks2014", table "dbo.TestDetails", column 'MasterID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

We can delete only those Master rows that don't have corresponding Details. In this example it is only `3, 4`.

Find `MasterID` which can't be deleted first:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[TestDetails].MasterID
FROM [dbo].[TestDetails]
WHERE [dbo].[TestDetails].MasterID IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Which returns:

```
MasterID
1
2
```

Edit your original list of IDs and remove conflicting IDs from it, then you can run the final `DELETE`:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[TestMaster]
WHERE ID IN (3, 4);
```

**Single query**

Instead of running a separate `SELECT`, retrieving a list of conflicting IDs to the client over the network, adjusting the original list of IDs, running the final `DELETE` you can make a single query that does it all. For this simple example it can look like this:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[TestMaster]
WHERE 
    [dbo].[TestMaster].ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
    AND [dbo].[TestMaster].ID NOT IN
    (
        SELECT [dbo].[TestDetails].MasterID
        FROM [dbo].[TestDetails]
        WHERE [dbo].[TestDetails].MasterID IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
    );
```

This query will delete only two rows with IDs 3 and 4.

Comment: In a huge db we dont know what are the tables with relationships. We just need to delete the records with no conflicts and find others. Thats it.

Comment: Relational databases, such as SQL Server are designed to work with stable and known schema. Working with unknown or dynamic schema is usually difficult. You can try to extract the needed info about constraints from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and system tables. OR, delete rows one-by-one.

Answer (score 1):

By Default if your sql statment fails then the transaction will be rolled back. And you cannot meet your need if you are doing through single statement where you need to get the erroneous one

May be you can follow the approach given below

```
    try
    {
        using (var sc = new SqlConnection(dbConnString))
        using (var cmd = sc.CreateCommand())
        {
            sc.Open();
            var nosConcat = "1,2,3,4,5";
            string failedIds = string.Empty;
            var ids = nosConcat.Split(',');
            string @delTblName = "sometable";
            string @delColumnName = "somecolumn";
            for(int i = 0 ; i < ids.Length ; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM " + @delTblName + " WHERE " + @delColumnName + " = @valConcat ";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valConcat", ids[i]);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.Errors[0].Number == 444) //Use the actual error number that you get on foreign key confilict
                        failedIds += "," + ids[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
```

Comment: More exact: Any sensible database follows ACID principles. The A stands for ATOMIC. A statement (or group of statements in a transaction) is either executed completely, or not at all. Fundamental db principle.

Answer (score 1):

If you needed to just delete, it would have been an easy answer - batch the delete statements and wrap them in a transaction. But since you want the keys that caused an issue, and you cannot use stored procedures, that makes the problem tricky.

Here is a thought experiment that might get you closer to what you want. The idea is this:

1. Process the delete in batches. I see no way around that without using stored procedures.
2. In each batch:

   - Try to delete all the records (maximum "window" size)
   - If the delete fails, try to delete the records in a smaller "window".
   - Keep trying and decreasing the "window" until a problem record is found.
   - On a single error add that value to the list of errors.
   - Continue checking each record.
   - if the next delete succeeds, confidently increase the "window" size.

The "window" size adjusts the number of records in the batch to process.

---

At the end you would have deleted what you can, and will have a list of values that failed to delete.

Unfortunately you cannot run a delete and get the list of values that gave problems (database transactions don't work like that) but the "binary search-like" method above will at least be faster than checking each value in the 15k list... only if there are a a small number of conflicts. Otherwise it won't be any faster.

---

Here is the code that details the steps:

```
int batchSize = 1024; // define this elsewhere
// allValuesToDel is your list of values. I've just defined it as an empty list
var allValuesToDel = new List<int>();
var valueErrors = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < allValuesToDel.Count; i += batchSize)
{
    using (var sc = new SqlConnection(dbConnString))
    {
        sc.Open();
        var valueBatch = allValuesToDel.Skip(i)
            .Take(batchSize)
            // annotating each value with a 'processed' flag allows us to track them
            .Select(k => new { Value = k, Processed = false }).ToList();

        // the starting window size
        int windowSize = valueBatch.Count;
        while (valueBatch.Count > 0 && valueBatch.Any(o => !o.Processed))
        {
            // get the unprocessed values within the window
            var valuesToDel = valueBatch.Where(k => !k.Processed).Take(windowSize).ToList();
            string nosConcat = string.Join(",", valuesToDel.Select(k => k.Value));
            try
            {
                using (var cmd = sc.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("DELETE FROM {0} WHERE {1} IN ({2})", tblName, delColumnName, nosConcat); 
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                // on success we can mark them as processed
                valuesToDel.ForEach(k => k.Processed = true);

                // Since delete worked, let's try on more records
                windowSize = windowSize * 2;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                if (windowSize == 1)
                {
                    // we found a value that failed - add that to the list of failures
                    valueErrors.Add(valuesToDel[0].Value);
                    valuesToDel.ForEach(k => k.Processed = true); // mark it as processed
                }

                // decrease the window size (until 1) to try and catch the problematic record
                windowSize = (windowSize / 2) + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```